# Java - problems with inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

I have this two classes:

```
public class Superclass 
{
  public Superclass();

  ...

}
```

and

```
public class ChildClass extends Superclass
{
  public ChildClass();

  public setname(String name)
  {
   ...
  }

}
```

if I do this:

```
Superclass a;
a = new ChildClass();
a.setname("Roger");
```

i get this warning: The method setname(String) is undefined for the type Superclass.
How to resolve? Thanks

Comment: It's telling you that it knows that the object is of type `ChildClass` so it will perform the function but in other cases this would break. I would suggest using interfaces to understand inheritance more completely.

Comment: @ars265 - On the contrary, the compiler is telling you that the method cannot be called on the *reference* of type `Superclass`. It won't perform the function -- it won't even compile.

Comment: @AndyThomas, That's is what I thought but he said it was only throwing a Warning, not an Error so I made the assumption that it still compiled. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the variable as:

```
ChildClass a = new ChildClass();
```

You can still pass it into a method that takes an argument of type SuperClass. The idea is that a subclass should be substitutable for any of its superclasses.

Answer (score 6):

When you call a method through a reference of the `Superclass` type, you're limited to the Superclass API. The Superclass API does not include the method `setname()`.

You could fix this by declaring the method in the superclass. In this example, it's declared as abstract so that the superclass does not need to define it.

```
public abstract class Superclass 
{
  public Superclass();

  public abstract void setname(String name);
}
```

Or you could change the type of the reference `a` to the subclass:

```
ChildClass a;
a = new ChildClass();
a.setname("Roger");
```

Comment: .. or this works as well, related to my comment on the question.

Comment: the problem is that i need a to be an object of type Superclass as i have to pass it to a function of the tipe method(Superclass) but at the same time i have to set its attributes with methods of the ChildClass..

Comment: Your subclass can provide an implementation for a method that's declared in the superclass. At runtime, the actual method called will be the one in the subclass.

Comment: @beworker - Thanks for catching the missing "abstract" in a parallel edit.

Answer (score 2):

Create a variable 'a' as

```
Childclass a = new Childclass();
a.setName("Roger");
```

Answer (score 1):

`a` is a reference of `Superclass` type so it can only access the things present in `Superclass`. If you want access `setname` using the parent reference, then you need to have that method in parent class also.

Attributes and method accessible to a reference are only those which are present int reference class/interface and not in the containing object.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating object of SuperClass type by using ChildClass only you can access the member and methods of SuperClass and subclass the reverse is not possible.
**ChildClass a=new ChildClass();**
this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In parent child relationship you can take the reference of parent and can create the object of child as you have done.

```
Superclass a;
a = new ChildClass();
```

but there is one condition that is the object `a` follows the blueprint of its reference class, which means that in your case `a` has a reference of Superclass so `a` has the access of all the methods which are defined in Superclass not in ChildClass.

So your call to `a.setname("Roger");` is not valid because `a` is of type Superclass which doesn't have `setname(String) method but if you do something like`ChildClass a = new ChildClass()`then your call to`a.setname("Roger");`will be valid because`a`is of type ChildClass which has`setname(String) method.`

One more thing, lets suppose you have a structure as  :

```
class SuperClass
{
    public SuperClass();
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        System.out.println("setName() of SuperClass with name "+name);
    }
}

class ChildClass extends SuperClass
{
    public ChildClass();
    public void setName(String name)
    {
        System.out.println("setName() of ChildClass with name "+name);
    }
}
```

and you call it in main like :

```
    ChildClass a;
a = new ChildClass();
a.setname("Roger");
```

so it will compile and run fine with an output

setName() of ChildClass with name Roger.

and I am sure you know the real reason of this output now. :)

Answer (score -1):

Declare method `setname` as abstract in super class.

```
public abstract class Superclass 
{
  public Superclass(){
   }
  public abstract setname(String name);
}
```